# How long before a process automatically dies by itself

Tags: linux, time, process

I am trying to optimize the time how many times my cron job runs to create a python script.
I want to know how can I find or know before a process dies by itself so that way I can run my cron job accordingly

Trying to setup the time schedule of my cron job to run a python script on linux server

no code

Comment: Processes don't have any automatic time limit.

Comment: I really don't understand your question...

Comment: If I set my cron job to run every 4 hour to run a python job, will the python job be running for 4 hours ?

Comment: your python script will only run for the amount of time it takes to complete all steps in the code. That could be 1, 10, 100,000 seconds or more. If you code has a `while` loop that never returns false, it can run forever. You are responsible for determining when to stop your script and `crontab` is NOT the way to achieve that, your code will have to know when to stop. Good luck.

Comment: Another way to look at is is to have your program run "forever" and then have an external process to kill your program, but that is not the optimal design pattern. OR you code can look for a special file, and if found, then go thru  clean up and exit steps. An external process or protocol would place that special file based on rules decided by you. Good luck.